# Toggle google maps style items

Tags: javascript, google-maps

What is the best way to toggle google maps v3 style objects as highways, water, locality etc...

We have tried with concat to add elements to the styles array but with no succes.

```
citynamesArray = [{
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "on" // 
        }
    ]
},];
mapoptions.concat(citynamesArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    var myStyles =[
        {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on" // 
            }
        ]
        }
    ];

    var mapOptions = {

        styles: myStyles 
    };

    map.setOptions(mapOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks problem is we have a custom map style, so we want users of the map to toggle some things such as highways, locality, parcs, etc

Comment: In this way you can  set your style in the  way you want and then with setOptions you can apply this change to the map.  Is this what you need or not?